# What is wrong with my equals method?

Tags: java, equals, complex-numbers

I am writing a Complex number class and my equals method doesn't seem to be working. I'm supposed to be checking to see if two ComplexNum objects are equal to each other and I am always coming across a logic error that always returns false.

```
public boolean equals(Object x) {
    ComplexNum real = (ComplexNum) x;
    if (x == null)
        return false;
    if (x instanceof ComplexNum && this.imag == (real.real)) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

This is my demo class

```
ComplexNum y = new ComplexNum(3.0,15.0);
ComplexNum z = new ComplexNum(3.0,15.0);

    System.out.println(y.equals(z));
```

false < -- my output is false no matter what the values are

Comment: Look up testing for floating point equality. That's your problem, since the digital representation of a floating point number is *never* exact (except in certain infrequent circumstances) and so `==` should not be used to test for equality of these entities.

Comment: You are comparing the imaginary part of **this** to the **real** part of the other.  Also, don't name the other one "real", that's very confusing.

Comment: I don't think you should be comparing `real` of one value to `imag` of the other, should you?

Comment: IMHO, this is not the place for arguments about whether epsilon comparisons are more appropriate.   IMHO (again) the `.equals()` method should perform _exactly_ what `==` does for floats, and epsilon-based comparison should be done in another method.

Comment: NB: this original code would cause a `ClassCastException` if the passed object is not a `ComplexNum` because you perform the cast in the first line, without checking the type with `instanceof` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not performing a like-for-like comparison on the real and imaginary components of your complex number.

This would be my implementation:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof ComplexNum) {
        ComplexNum other = (ComplexNum)o;
        return (this.real == other.real) && (this.imag == other.imag);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For those arguing that floating point comparison should never use precise tests, IMHO that should be in another method.  Java requires that objects that are `.equal()` have the same `.hashCode()`, and that would be *very* hard to arrange with an epsilon comparison.

Because of the above, you will need this, too (other implementations are possible, and the below assumes that your components are `double`)

```
int hashCode() {
    return Double(this.real).hashCode() ^ Double(this.imag).hashCode();
}
```

NB: A test for `o == null` is not necessary in `.equals()`, because `null` is *not* an `instanceof ComplexNum`.

**EDIT** for *completely strict* conformance with the way that `.equals()` works on `Float` or `Double` types (particularly for NaN values) you might want to use this line instead which replaces `==` with a per-component application of `.equals()`

```
return Double(this.real).equals(other.real) &&
       Double(this.imag).equals(other.imag);
```